# how to get currentUser in client side in nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I use next13 new app dir and nextAuth.

This code below returns currentUser on the server side successfully, but not on the client side!

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

import prisma from "@/app/hooks/libs/prismadb";
import { authOptions } from "@/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";

export async function getSession() {
  return await getServerSession(authOptions)
}

export default async function getCurrentUser() {

  try {
    const session = await getSession();
    if (!session?.user?.email) {
      return null;
    }

    const currentUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        email: session.user.email as string,
      }
    });

    if (!currentUser) {
      return null;
    }

    return currentUser

  } catch (error: any) {
    return null;
  }

}
```

**So, how to get currentUser on the client side?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top-level root layout, wrap it with `SessionProvider`

```
<SessionProvider>
  <Navbar />
  <main>{children}</main>
</SessionProvider>
```

then in any client component

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const {data:session}=useSession()
```